# Why (1.1-1.0)*10 isn't 1.0?

Tags: c

Why result of this code is false? I can't solve this problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
if ( (1.1 - 1.0)*10.0 - 1.0 == 0.0 )
    printf("True");
else
    printf("False");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/588004

Comment: Because floating point is the devil. I've said it before, I'll keep saying it until people understand.

Comment: 1.1 is not exactly the rational number 11/10. It is rather the [dyadic rational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational) whose value is closest to 11/10.

Answer (score 6):

Chasing equality in floating point is mostly a fools game.

Best you can do is decide upon a delta that's 'close enough' and compare with that.

google told me to read this for more information:  http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm

Answer (score 1):

But this works as you wanted:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    float x,y;
    x=0.0;
    y=0.0;

    x=1.1 - 1.0;
    x=x*10.0;
    x=x-1.0;

    if (   x==y )
        printf("True");
    else
        printf("False");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think there's any guarantee that this will work. All you've done is replace a single expression with a series of assignments.

Comment: Please compile and run.

Answer (score 0):

Most `double` math uses a [binary floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) representation.  So `1.1` is not *exactly* representable - just something close to it.  Consider the following which uses `volatile` to prevent compiler optimizations.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  volatile double wpw = 1.1;
  volatile double one = 1.0;
  volatile double ten = 10.0;
  printf("%.20e\n", wpw);
  printf("%.20e\n", wpw - one);
  printf("%.20e\n", (wpw - one) * ten);
  printf("%.20e\n", (wpw - one) * ten - one);
  return 0;
}
```

And it output below.  `1.1 - 1.0` is only *approximately* `0.1`.

```
1.10000000000000008882e+00
1.00000000000000088818e-01
1.00000000000000088818e+00
8.88178419700125232339e-16
```